# GKE Internal Ingress http -> https redirect

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, internal-load-balancer, google-cloud-internal-load-balancer

My setup:

I have a web app, service and an internal Ingress (Internal application load balancer) that i setup like [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress?hl=de). The website is only available within our vpc and our corporate vpn. I created a self signed certificate for testing a https and it is working. Now I would like to have a FrontEndConfig rule that redirect the traffic from http to https. According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration?hl=de) Document the Internal Ingress doesn't support http to https redirect. Is there other possible solutions for this problem?

Comment: Did you try it with the internal Ingress?  The internal application load balancer supports this now so it might work.

Comment: Also, are you open to using the Gateway API rather than Ingress?

Comment: @GariSingh Hey! I had tried but it didnt work. Where did you get the info that is also working for Internal ingress?

Comment: The Gateway API is too overkill for our use case, so we decided to use Ingress

Comment: I actually don't think it works with Internal Ingress.  At this point, support for new load balancing features is added to Gateway API rather than Ingress.   https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-gateways#configure_http-to-https_redirects